# Histogram of subblock matrix

Tags: matlab, histogram

Given some matrix, I want to divide it into blocks of size `2-by-2` and show a histogram for each of the blocks. The following is the code I wrote to solve the problem, but the sum of the histograms I'm generating is not the same as the histogram of the whole matrix. Actually the the sum of the blocks' histograms is double what I expected. What am I doing wrong?

```
im =[1 1 1 2 0 6 4 3; 1 1 0 4 2 9 1 2; 1 0 1 7 4 3 0 9; 2 3 4 7 8 1 1 4; 9 6 4 1 5 3 1 4; 1 3 5 7 9 0 2 5; 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0; 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4];
display(imhist(im));
[r c]=size(im);
bs = 2; % Block Size (8x8)
nob=[r c ]./ bs; % Total number of Blocks
% Dividing the image into 8x8 Blocks
kk=0;
for k=1:nob/2
    for i=1:(r/bs)
        for j=1:(c/bs)
            Block(:,:,kk+j)=im((bs*(i-1)+1:bs*(i-1)+bs),(bs*(j-1)+1:bs*(j-1)+bs));
            count(:,:,kk+j)=sum(sum(sum(hist(Block(:,:,kk+j)))));
            p=sum(count(:,:,kk+j));
        end
        kk=kk+(r/bs);
    end
end
```

Comment: Phew. Please reformat your code and question! You can read the manual [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Please use proper indentation of your code! Also: It is not clear to me what you are actually asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason they aren't the same is because you use imhist for im and hist for the blocks. Hist separates data into 10 different bins based on your data range, imhist separates data based on the image type. Since your arrays are doubles, the imhist bins are from 0 to 1.0 Thats why your imhist has only values at 0, and 1. The hist produces bins based on your data range, so it will actually change slightly depending on what value you pass in. So you cant simply add bins together. Even though they are the same size vector 10x1 , the values in them can be very different. in one set bin(1) can be the range 1-5 but in another set of data bin(1) could be 1-500.

To fix all these issues I used imhist, and converted your data to uint8. At the very end I subtract the two histograms from one another and get zero, this shows that they are indeed the same

```
im =uint8([1 1 1 2 0 6 4 3 ;
           1 1 0 4 2 9 1 2 ;
           1 0 1 7 4 3 0 9 ;
           2 3 4 7 8 1 1 4 ; 
           9 6 4 1 5 3 1 4 ; 
           1 3 5 7 9 0 2 5 ; 
           1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 ; 
           1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 ]); 
orig_imhist = imhist(im);
%% next thing
[r c]=size(im);
bs=2; % Block Size (8x8)
nob=[r c ]./ bs; % Total number of Blocks

%creates arrays ahead of time
block = uint8(zeros(bs,bs,nob(1)*nob(2)));
%we use 256, because a uint8 has 256 values, or 256 'bins' for the
%histogram
block_imhist = zeros(256,nob(1)*nob(2));
sum_block_hist = zeros(256,1);

% Dividing the image into 2x2 Blocks
for i = 0:nob(1)-1
   for j = 0:nob(2)-1

      curr_block = i*nob(1)+(j+1);
      %creates the 2x2 block
      block(:,:,curr_block) = im(bs*i+1:bs*i+ bs,bs*j+1:bs*j+ bs);

      %creates a histogram for the block
      block_imhist(:,curr_block) = imhist(block(:,:,curr_block));

      %adds the current histogram to the running sum
      sum_block_hist = sum_block_hist + block_imhist(:,curr_block);
   end
end
%shows that the two are the same
sum(sum(orig_imhist-sum_block_hist))
```

if my solution solves your problem please mark it as the answer